# Change encoding type for all files or whole project

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, encoding

How can we change encoding mode for the whole project rather than doing to single shapefiles in QGIS 3.4?

I wanted to change `"UTF-8"` to `"Shift_JIS"` to all project vector files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use a python script for that task:

```
group = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().children()
layers = [ item.layer() for item in group ] #list of all layers
for layer in layers:
    layer.setProviderEncoding('Shift_JIS')
    layer.dataProvider().setEncoding('Shift_JIS')
```

save the script to a file.py and open it from the Python console->Editor